# Kill and Restart TeamViewer 10 Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, command-line, teamviewer

How do I kill and restart TeamViewer 10 on ubuntu from the command line?

I tried running `sudo kill -HUP teamviewer*` and other variants (TeamViewer.exe; which I got from the system monitor) with no luck.

I have an issue sometimes with Teamviewer hanging and it would be nice not to have to reboot my system to get TV10 working again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`kill` accepts PIDs, not process command names. Try `pkill`, or `killall`:

```
sudo pkill TeamViewer.exe
```

Or:

```
sudo pkill -f TeamViewer.exe
```

Comment: The pkill command did the trick to kill TeamViewer. How do I restart?

Comment: @NotMy1RealName how do you usually start it?

Comment: It starts at boot. However, the issue is that the program crashes at times and needs to be killed and restarted. I've `xkill` 'd the program, but I can't restart it unless I reboot. Very inconvenient.

Answer (score 37):

In other versions of teamviewer some times the daemon has to be restarted the in order to run the teamviewer app again after closing it.

```
sudo teamviewer --daemon stop
sudo teamviewer --daemon start
```

or

```
sudo teamviewer --daemon restart
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. It's probably a much more elegant way to do it than *kill*ing the process.

Answer (score 5):

These work too:

```
sudo service teamviewerd stop
sudo service teamviewerd start
```

Answer (score 5):

In Ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo systemctl stop teamviewerd.service
sudo systemctl start teamviewerd.service
```

or

```
sudo systemctl restart teamviewerd.service
```

Comment: For me It also worked without the ending `.service`.